# I need Google Settings again in my phone, but I can't install it again without the Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, google-settings

I have uninstalled an application called "Google Settings" by accident. So now whenever I go to the Google Play Store it says "server error". Whatsapp need to be updated, but for me to do update it I need Google Play Stpr BUT Google Play Store doesn't work without the app Google Settings. How do I install again the Google Settings again w/o using Google Play Store?